# Outputing Logs in Reporter Cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, cypress

I am writing a test kit on cypress for my web application. One thing I want to be able to do is display certain data about the state of the application appended to each test so I know the particulars of that user's configuration. For example, the url of the test, whether the user has certain permissions or not etc. I am using mochawesome for the reporting but am not entirely partial to it. Is there some way to add data that comes from cy.get, cy.find... commands to the reporting?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Add this to support/commands.js

```
import addContext from 'mochawesome/addContext';
Cypress.Commands.add('addContext', (context) => {
  cy.once('test:after:run', (test) => addContext({ test }, context));
});
```

Then use the function through cy.addContext("whatever").
It will get added to the mochawesome test file.